# Выход за пределы списка [IndexError]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Собственно никак не могу понять причины выхода за пределы списка по условию word[i] == ' '
Код должен создавать список из строки word и удалять пробелы

```
word ='gy sn eg gf wi me gf'
word = list(word)
print(word)
s = len(word)
for i in range(s):
    if word[i] == ' ':
        word.pop(i)
        print('удалили пробел на ', i)

print(word)
```

Comment: а не вариент просто сделать `word.split(" ")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выход за пределы получается из-за того, что вы удаляя из списка, уменьшаете его размер. Размер и его индексы были составлены до удаления.

Решением может быть удаление в обратном порядке -- с конца в начало, тогда проблем не будет:

```
...
for i in reversed(range(s)):
...
```

---

**PS.**

В вашей задаче можно просто воспользоваться `split`:

```
word = 'gy sn eg gf wi me gf'
word = word.split()
print(word)
```

---

**PPS.**

Еще можно было при переборе символов той строки, составить список без пробела:

```
word ='gy sn eg gf wi me gf'
new_words = [c for c in word if c != ' ']
print(new_words)
```

Comment: Ну я же ввел переменную S для того что бы размер списка был статическим, или она все-таки как-то пересчитывается при каждом новом вхождении в цикл ?

Comment: спасибо за split

Comment: Все понял, можете не отвечать, спасибо

Comment: @ДенисБусоргин, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)